# Difficulties to export database from phpmyadmin after xampp v3.3.0 update - [Failed-network error | courupted gzip file]

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Recently updated Xampp version to 3.3.0 and the problem is while I am exporting the database from phpmyadmin...

1. exporting in sql -> it will say failed-network error
2. exporting gzipped -> it will export of the size around 73 KB and if I open that file it is saying the archive is either unknown format or damaged.

below are the images

[image: network error image]

[image: damaged file error image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71810999/export-failed-network-error-when-i-exporting-from-phpmyadmin This helped me, hope the same for you.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. While not really a solution I was able to work around this by choosing the custom option in the export options and then choosing view output as text. This worked, I could copy the text and paste it where I needed it.

Comment: yes  this is your way is ok but for me the size of sql file around 48 MB so its difficult for me... appreciate your reply...thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use custom options and compression to e.g. gzip!