# Export Failed - Network error when i exporting from phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
PHP version: 8.1.4
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the orignal question is [Failed - Network error when i exporting from phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615310/failed-network-error-when-i-exporting-from-phpmyadmin) but as there is no correct solution here is the solution.

https://gist.github.com/harshrajdubey/653b4a54227049ad288875e9d52a009a/ba12fd65068052a5e07828568b2903c5f459b491

Replace phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Core.php with the above file and it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much it really helped me in xampp 8.0.17

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP for Windows 8.1.5, phpmyadmin 5.1.3 - works! thx!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).